# It is not possible to addEventListener to the button added with the EventListener

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom-events, addeventlistener

I have two functions that redraw part of my page by clicking on a button, each of which after rendering should add an eventlistener to the drawn button.

```
    showItem () {
        const Id = this.dataset.product_id;
        const ItemBlock = document.getElementById(Id)
        const Template = renderItemNormalView();
        const HTML = Template(ItemBlock.dataset);
        ItemBlock.innerHTML = HTML;
        const editBtn = ItemBlock.querySelector('.js-edit-item');
        editBtn.addEventListener('click', this.showItemEditor);
    }

    showItemEditor () {
        const id = this.dataset.product_id;
        const itemBlock = document.getElementById(id);
        const template = renderItemEditView();
        const HTML = template(itemBlock.dataset);
        itemBlock.innerHTML = HTML;
        const saveChanges = itemBlock.querySelector('.js-save-item-changes');
        saveChanges.addEventListener('click', this.showItem);
    }
```

The first time the function showItemEditor is called by click, but after rendering a page, showItem is not added as onclick. I am new to js so I don't understand what the problem might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that was tricky, for me atleast. The problem was, that 'this' for both my function was not the class, that contains them, but the buttons, on which i tried to put onclick, so expressions 'this.showItem'and 'this.showItemEditor' just made no sense. I'm suprised firefox did not tell me about that. But i'm glad it's all over :)